# Action when i change the status of an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, order-status, json

I need some help i want generate a json from orders completed, if i change the status order into admin panel, i want to make a json of that order.

Could you help me, how can i execute a script or action, when i change status of an order to **Completed** ?

[image]

i'm not sure if i can do it with, **catalog_product_save_before**, could u help me to do it?

Comment: It should work. Get order data via `$data = $this->getOrder()->getData()` then `json_encode($data)` and do whatever you need to with it

Comment: but where ? or what i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event `sales_order_save_after`.

In event, if the order status has changed to complete then generate a JSON representation of the order data:

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderStatusChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $stateComplete = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
        // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
        if ($order->getStatus() == $stateComplete && $order->getOrigData('state') != $stateComplete) {
            $data =  $order->getData();
            $data['billing'] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
            $data['shipping'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
            // your result
            $jsonData = json_encode($data);
            // do something with $jsonData...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I suggest providing an example of the XML for the observer subscription as well since the OP doesn't appear to understand the concept.

Comment: coul u helpme , what file i have to edit? or where i add this code? 
im noob with magento!!!